# Get li value and POST to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a treeview list, and I want to send the id of li select with ajax but I don't know why this code doesn't works

The code:
http://jsfiddle.net/esS4k/379/ (old)

The new code(http://jsfiddle.net/esS4k/385/), try it, the alert on li value is "undefined"

-HTML

```
<div id="content_table">
  <ul id="treeview">
  <li data-expanded="true">Item 1
      <ul>
          <li id="11">Item 1.1
            <ul>
              <li id="111">Item1.1.1</li>
              <li id="112">Item1.1.2</li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          <li id="12">Item 1.2</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-expanded="true">Item 2
      <ul>
          <li id="21">Item 2.1</li>
          <li id="22">Item 2.2</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

-jQuery/ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#treeview').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ldtree2.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: 'choice' + $("ul[name='treeview']>option:li.selected").val(),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
        $('#content_table').html(data);                                 
        }
    });
}); 
});
```

-ldtree2.php

```
<?php echo $_POST['choice'];?>
```

Have a good day

EDIT:
I think, the problem is because of the list structure

```
**<li>** <ul><li></li><li></li></ul> **<li>**
```

With the event

```
    $('#treeview li').on('click',function(){         
        alert( this.id);         
})
```

I have **2** alerts (1 with the "li" id and 1 with nothing)

Comment: Until you don't explain __how__ it doesn't work - have a good day.

Comment: First, 
$("ul[name='treeview']>option:li.selected").val() this should be $("ul#treeview>option:li.selected").val() as ul doent have "name" attribute.

Comment: use data attribute instead`<li data-id="111">Item1.1.1</li>`

Comment: Try: data: { 'choice' : $("ul[name='treeview']>option:li.selected").val() },

Comment: @Djip  It doesn't work

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile It doesn't work

Comment: @Tazz Can you update the Fiddle to include the ajax code above, as in where you is having that right now ?

Comment: @Djip I updated my Fiddle

Comment: @Tazz check my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will do the work for you. You just need to add `test` to all the child `ul`

```
var data={ choice:$(this).attr('id') };
$('#treeview .test li').on('click',function(){          
        $.ajax({
        url: "ldtree2.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
        $('#content_table').html(data);                                 
        }
    });            
});
```

NOTE : Tested the same in your fiddel, please check http://jsfiddle.net/esS4k/380/

Hope that helps.

Comment: On ldtree2.php I have "echo $_POST['choice'];" and with your code, I have "Undefined index: choice"

Comment: I was checking why that id was not going. You also need to set the data in proper way. Like :
var data={choice:$(this).attr('id')}
and change the data : data in $.ajax code. Hope it will work

Comment: Please check the answer modification made by me. Hope now it will be clear to you, and your code will work.

Comment: Where you have written the code, you will not get the ID value as the JQUERY plugin is implementing the styles and structure later on. So you need to call the ajax as previous. Hope I am understandable to you.

Comment: OK thank you for the information, when I use "alert", I have 2 alerts with nothing on second, it's why  I have "Undefined index: choice" (check my edit 1st post)

Comment: This is the fiddel I have written last time and it is showing a single alert. Hope this will work for you http://jsfiddle.net/esS4k/391/

Comment: Thank but for exampleif you click on "1.1.1" you have 2 alerts ! On "ldtree.php" with the code "echo $_GET['choice']" works but with POST, I have an error "Undefined index: choice"

Comment: It's OK now with class="test" on last children of my tree http://jsfiddle.net/esS4k/392/

Comment: I am unable to understand your comments, after its work perfectly how it started not working. Please check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/esS4k/394/ where I find the same is working.... Please check your PHP code, or if you need $_GET to work, remove method "POST" from $.ajax...hope that works..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "value" attribute instead of id to hold your values and then .val() will give you the value.

```
<li id="whatever" value="112">Item1.1.2</li>
```

In your Fiddle you use Kendoo Treeview so you should handle this in your selected part.

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    select: function (e) {
        // When a node is selected, display the text for the node in the dropdown and hide the treeview.
        $dropdownRootElem.find("span.k-input").text($(e.node).children("div").text());
        $treeviewRootElem.slideToggle('fast', function() {
            $treeviewRootElem.removeClass("k-custom-visible");
        });
        // get data from selected node (taken from treeview api documentation)
        var data = $('#treeview').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.node);
        //Better put this in a extra function
        $.ajax({
            url: "ldtree2.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: 'choice' + data.id, //u can get the id from the node data 
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#content_table').html(data);                                 
            }
       });
    }
}).data("kendoTreeView");
var $treeviewRootElem = $(treeview.element).closest("div.k-treeview");
```

Comment: Can you check my new Fiddle pls ? I try but your data.id returns "Undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample code. Hope it'll help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $( ".list" ).click(function(event) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            var list_id = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log('list_id : '+list_id);

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "server.php",
                data: { list_id: list_id}
            }).done(function( response ) {
                console.log('Response Data', response);

            });
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content_table">
        <ul id="treeview">
            <li data-expanded="true">Item 1
              <ul>
                  <li class="list" id="11">Item 1.1
                    <ul>
                      <li class="list" id="111">Item1.1.1</li>
                      <li class="list" id="112">Item1.1.2</li>
                    </ul>
                   </li>
                  <li class="list" id="12">Item 1.2</li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li data-expanded="true">Item 2
              <ul>
                  <li class="list" id="21">Item 2.1</li>
                  <li class="list" id="22">Item 2.2</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, not sure it will work or not.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var option_data=$("ul#treeview>option:li.selected").val(); // this line according to @JoshulSharma
        var formData = {
        'choice' : option_data,
        };

        $('#treeview').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                    url: "ldtree2.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {
                    $('#content_table').html(data);                                 
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
```

PHP Part

```
echo $_POST['choice'];
```

Comment: below line is according to @JoshulSharma

$("ul#treeview>option:li.selected").val();

Answer (score 0):

I've cheked your updated fiddle, and found your mistake.
Replace the following two lines:

```
var data = $('#treeview').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.node);
alert(data.id);  //undefined !!
```

With:

```
var data = $(e.node).attr('id');
alert(data);
```

EDIT:
Just found that your $.ajax also should be changed slightly.
The data option should look like this:

```
data: {choice : data},
```